# Facebook : Get List of Online Friends Using Graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to Get list of users online without Facebook SDK.My fql Query is as below

```
 $fql = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square, online_presence
            FROM user
            WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle')
            AND uid IN (
                SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $user
            )";
```

And my graph URl is

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT uid, name, pic_square, online_presence FROM user WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle') AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = 1234)&access_token=xxxxxxtokenxxxxx&method=GET
```

But Above Url returning null data.

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Note: my token have friends_online_presence permission .I have 40 users online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `user_online_presence` or `friends_online_presence` permissions to view `online_presence`. (see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user)

Without these permissions you'll receive `online_presence` as `null`, and nothing will be filtered by this part of `WHERE`: `online_presence IN ('active', 'idle')`

If you'll remove this restriction from your query, you'll see the list of friends with their statuses (or nulls if you don't have this permission)