# Facebook Graph API: how to get online friends / or active last X minutes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Past & Now**

A few years back, Facebook supports FQL in v2.0 to retrieve online friends of an user ( [Facebook : Get List of Online Friends Using Graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937727/facebook-get-list-of-online-friends-using-graph-api) )

However this FQL is removed from v2.3, and what's worse is Facebook completely removed Chat API (XMPP) from April 2015.

**Goal**

Is it still possible to generate a list of Facebook friends and their last active time / currently online using Graph API / or any other method? (basically the same as chat window on Facebook desktop)

This would be useful:

- when a user wants to see who's online but don't want to let their friends know they're online atm
- or for a simple widget on phone screen, where user can have a quick look at who're online without the need of Facebook login (the widget gets data from 3rd party server which uses API / or some other method to provide that list)

Thanks alot for your input

Comment: _“when a user wants to see who's online but don't want to let their friends know they're online atm”_ – so the user who does not want to appear visible as online to others is supposed to get that same kind of information about their friends … you don’t think that’s a little contradictory …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible - because as you found out already, Facebook removed the required permission/endpoint. The only way would be implement your own routine for this. For example, by storing the timestamp of visiting users. Whenever a friend of that user visits your App too, you can show those to him. Of course it only works for users who authorized your App and youi can only detect if users are online/active in YOUR App, not on Facebook.